# High Volume Bulk Photo Scanning - Hardware and Software For The Job?

Tags: photos, scanning

Let's say that I have a nearly unlimited budget to purchase a high volume photo scanner and I would like the ability to scan both a) modern prints, which could be done through an ADF, and b) older, more fragile photos which would need to be hand scanned via a flatbed scanner.

What is the best hardware and software to accomplish this goal giving the priorities of:

1. Integrity of the original
2. Speed, as far as how many photos you can scan
3. Quality, must be at least decent

I can think of a few solutions, but even with the best of hardware it would require a lot of manual scanning on flatbeds. In this case, what software can handle mass processing of flatbed scans with the least amount of human intervention?

Answer (score 1):

Kodak s1220! Scans 40 pics per minute up to 8" wide at high resolution. There is also a flatbed component (additional fee). See a demo at http://thememorykeepercoach.blogspot.com.